# Переменные окружения - System и User PATH через консоль

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, path, environment-variables

Доброго времени суток!

Существует ли простой способ получить значение переменной окружения `PATH`,
отдельно для пользователя «**User**» и системы «**System**», с помощью консоли Windows
(`cmd.exe`) без обращения к ветвям реестра?

Код для PowerShell тоже подойдёт, но только если он будет работать
для версии **v1.0**, которая по-умолчанию предустановлена в Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать через реестр

```
   $PATH_USER =  'HKCU:\Environment\'
   $PATH_MACHINE ='HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\'
   Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $PATH_USER -name 'path' #чтение сред из реестра для пользователя (отдает в виде строки)
   Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $PATH_MACHINE -name 'path' #чтение сред из машины для пользователя (отдает в виде строки)
```

Можно попробовать через класс .NET

```
   ALL_PATH[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH','machine')
```

Answer (score 0):

- Shift + правый клик по Рабочему столу
- В меню выбрать [Открыть окно команд]
- В окне команд ввести `powershell`
- Вставить фрагмент кода

При этом переменная `PATH` будет записана в текстовый файл

```
$n = "`r`n"; $u = "(USR-PATH): $n$n"; $s = "(SYS-PATH): $n$n";
$usr = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','User');
$sys = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','Machine');
$u + $usr + $n + $n + $s + $sys + $n -split ';' > env.txt
```

По желанию, можно добавить следующий фрагмент, чтобы записать все переменные окружения:

```
ls env: >> env.txt
```